# "${PWD}" does not work when used with Make on Windows to mount a Docker volume

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, cmd, makefile

On a windows machine, I have a `Makefile` that contains the following instruction:

```
start_docker:
   docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 -it -v "${PWD}":/home/docker/app my_image
```

When I run `make start_docker` either in the PowerShell or cmd prompt, I get the following output:
`docker run -p 8888:8888 -it -v :/home/docker/app my_image`

(note that the output displays a blanck istead of the current path)

And then my local volume is not mounted.
However, if I paste directly `docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 -it -v "${PWD}":/home/docker/app my_image` the volume is mounted (great!).

I get an error  `"$(PWD)" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.` if I try to use it in the cmd prompt).

What should I do to start my docker image with make with the correct path in windows (it works smoothly on Linux)?

I also tried `${PWD}` and `$(pwd)`, it does not change the issue.

Comment: Try using `"$${PWD}"` to prevent `make` from expanding it

Comment: Thanx @MathiasR.Jessen !
It partially works: I see the `docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 -it -v "${PWD}":...` in the output of the function, but then I have the ` only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed` error (even if I execute it from the powershell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make doesn't set or use the variable `PWD` in any way.  If it is set, it is either because something in your makefile set it, or because it was inherited from the shell that invoked `make`.

If you run on a POSIX system like GNU/Linux or MacOS, then the shell will (often, but not always) set the `PWD` environment variable and `make` will inherit that.  But it's not always right, and not always set.  On Windows, the Windows shell (powershell or cmd.exe) do not set this variable, so it's never set.

In short, it's always a portability problem to use `PWD`.

If you like you could switch to using the GNU make variable `CURDIR`:

```
start_docker:
       docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 -it -v "${CURDIR}":/home/docker/app my_image
```

which is set by GNU `make` when it starts, and so always has a value.

Comment: Thank you! It works on window. I guess it should also works on Linux. 
In the powershell I do not see the output of the command (EDIT: it might take a very long time to appear), while I get it in CMD.